# Can I ask for some suggestions on how to approach this,please?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a field from the db called sections and I have the following checkbox control on the markup.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="sections" /> 
<label for="sections">Section values</label>
```

Then on codebehind, I use this code to render checkbox control with value property and actual value of Sections displayed just the way I want it.

```
Me.sections.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "Miracle Alley")
```

My issues now are 2 fold:

1, what is the best way to add CheckAll/UncheckAll feature to the markup so users can check a checkbox or checkboxes to display a value or values associated with checked box(es)?

2, We would like to declare a variable and assign the value of checked box to this variable.
For instance, if sections is checked then
var sectionsList = sections values.

Is this possible?

If not, any alternative solutions?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: sorry @LastStar007, I struggled what the appropriate wording of the the title quite frankly. I will improve on that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1)  please note that you should have 2 elements with IDs of `#checkAll` and `#unCheckAll` and load jQuery library :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkAll').click(function(){
       $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true)
    })

    $('#unCheckAll').click(function(){
       $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false)
    })
})
```

2)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
   var sectionsList = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
          return this.value
   })
   console.log(sectionsList)
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt response @Raminson. I am getting "Object Expected" error. I have posted the latest code.

Comment: @Kenny you are welcome, please remove my answer from the question :). it makes ma answer redundant.  note that you should have 2 elements with IDs of `#checkAll` and `#unCheckAll` and load jQuery library.

Comment: I am sorry. I have removed it. I only posted it so you could see what I could be doing wrong with your code. I downloaded this library but still getting same error: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js: The error points to these lines:

       $('#checkAll').click(function () {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true)
        })

Comment: have you used script tags? `<script type='text/javascript src='code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'>` or  `<script type='text/javascript src='path/to/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'>` ?

Comment: Yes, of course I have and that's exactly what I did @Raminson. I only showed you just the library that I used to be sure I am using the correct library

Comment: I am very sorry, I tried updating my comment to indicate that the error is gone and what I did to get rid of it but I got a message that I have to wait 5 seconds. I am reposting that now.
I changed the single tick mark to double quotes and that took care of it but I am only able to show just one checkbox even though I have  3:

        Me.url.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "Miracle Alleyt")
        Me.url.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "Broadway Musical")
        Me.url.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "ALl the Kings Men")

Comment: I am only seeing one checkbox but I have 3 so far:

Me.url.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "Miracle Alleyt")
 Me.url.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "Broadway Musical")
 Me.url.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "ALl the Kings Men") 

I understand that I have to add the 2 elements for CheckALl and UncheckALl but I would like to see as many checkboxes as are available to display.

Do I need to do something else to make this happen?

Thanks alot for your patience Raminson.

Comment: that's all the checkbox being rendered so far. The remaining 2 are not rendering.

    <div> 
        <span class="checkAll"><input id="sections" type="checkbox" name="sections" Value="Miracle Alley" /></span> 
        <label for="sections">CheckBox Item Text</label>
    </div>

Comment: yes @Raminson, precisely what I am looking for except I want that generated dynamically. In other words, I query the db to populate the checkbox values. I will look up how to do this tomorrow.  Thanks so much for your assistance and heavenly patience.